# High scores in preferences - thread

Tags: android, multithreading, preferences

I know there are lots of posts on how to use shared preferences to store high scores.  I know how to do this.  My problem, and I was not able to find an answer on the web, is as follows:

I have a HighScoreActivity where with onResume I "get" my scores preferences to display using the corresponding HighScoreView class.  Works well.

In my GameActivity, in onStop I "put" my current scores in preferences.  Which works well ONLY when the user exit the game screen(activity) to go to the menu screen(activity).  If the user tap the screen after a gameover state (we are now in GameView class with the running thread) to start a new game, these scores will NOT of course get saved in the preferences since onStop is not called!

How do I get the preferences updated from the GameView surfaceview class???  If someone could provide some directions it would be greatly appreciated since I have searched for days for an answer.

Comment: What technology/languages is this in?

Comment: It is in Android, sorry I forgot to mention it.  I have solved the problem.